# Uniswap V2: TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int_const -1" to "uint256"

Tags: uniswap, hardhat, compiler, library

I was trying to fork Uniswap V2 with another protocole and ran into this error while compiling the contracts: `TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int_const -1" to "uint256".`

The compiler didn't wanted to compile the @uniswap/lib library while it compiled on another similar project.

Answer (score 1):

After finding no answer across the internet, I figured out that this is probably because of a breaking Solidity version (probably older than 0.8.0). So if your @uniswap/lib libraries get compiled with a too recent solc compiler version, it will break.

The solution was to change the pragma version from >=0.5.0 to ^0.6.6. And contracts did compile this time.